# Why the spread operator will directly affect the state and sometime it doesn't? (React)

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactJS, however there is something that confuses me like why when I copy a simple object using the spread operator and modify its content, the object in the state is not affected. However, if I create a copy of an array using the same way and changes its content then the object in the state is now modified as reflected to what has been done to the copy.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    value: { id: 5, count: 0 },
  };

  sampleFunction = () => {
    let sampleValue = { ...this.state.value };
    sampleValue.count--;
    console.log(this.state.value.count);
    console.log(sampleValue.count);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // Ajax Call
    console.log("App - Mounted");
    this.sampleFunction();
  }
}
```

result : 
 0 
 -1

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    value: [{ id: 5, count: 0 }],
  };

  sampleFunction = () => {
    let sampleValue = [...this.state.value];
    sampleValue[0].count--;
    console.log(this.state.value[0].count);
    console.log(sampleValue.[0]count);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // Ajax Call
    console.log("App - Mounted");
    this.sampleFunction();
  }
}
```

result : 
-1 
 -1

what is the concept behind this?

Comment: spread syntax creates a shallow copy of the array. The objects inside the cloned and the original arrays are still the same.

Comment: @adiga so the exception is when the copy is an array and the modification is targeted to a specific element of that copy?

Comment: Only a new array is created. If you were to `push` to the new array, original array will not be mutated. But the objects in both the arrays are still the same. As in, they will satisfy the `===` check.

Comment: This applies to nested objects as well. `const a = { b: { c: 1 } }; const clone = { ...a }`. Here, it only creates a shallow copy of the object. The nested object `{ c: 1 }` is the same in both the objects. So, if you `a.b.c = 4` and check the value of `clone.b.c`, it will also be `4`

Comment: is it something similar to pass by references in c++?

Comment: I'm not familiar with c++. The object inside the cloned array and the original array point to the same reference, yes. But, the cloned array and the original array both have different points in memory. So, `originalArray.push(1)` will not have any effect on the `clonedArray`

Comment: thanks, I think I get it now, i follow your concepts and done some research, it seems that when the original array is an array that contain another arrays or objects, the said arrays or objects is actually a pointer that points to the said arrays or objects. Hence, when we copy the array, the elements inside the copy are also pointers that point to the same arrays or objects, that explained why it will affect both the original and the copy

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the former case, the spread syntax creates a shallow copy of the the `this.state.value` object. sampleValue is an independent object with its own `count` value.

```js
// new object with independent count property
let sampleValue = { ...this.state.value };
```

In the latter case, the spread syntax creates a new array, but the array's entries point at the same objects that are in the original. Modifications to those objects are reflected in both places because they are the same objects.

```js
// new array, but contains the original objects
// sampleValue[0] and this.state.value[0] are literally the same object
let sampleValue = [...this.state.value];
```

You can see this concretely in the following example:

```js
const someObject = { bananas: 1, wookies: 3};

// two arrays containing the same object
const firstArr = [someObject];
const secondArr = [someObject];

firstArr[0].bananas = 4; // modifies the shared object
console.log(secondArr[0].bananas); // 4

someObject.wookies = 42; // modifies the shared object
console.log(firstArr[0].wookies); // 42
console.log(secondArr[0].wookies); // 42
```

Comment: so the original will only be affected if a specific element in a copy of an array is targeted?

Comment: In the array version, `sampleValue[0]` and `this.state.value[0]` are literally the same object. Modifications to one will be reflected in the other because they are literally the same object.